# Non-isomorphic algebras with equal Hilbert-Poincaré series

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $A,B$  be two finite-dimensional graded algebras and let $P_A(x),P_B(z)$ be theirs Poincaré series. Suppose now  that $P_A(x)=P_B(z)$.

**Question.** Is it implies that $A \cong B?$

Comment: I think you may want to search Hilbert scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** $A=\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ and $B=\mathbb R[x,y]/(xy,x^2-y^2)$ have the same Hilbert (Poincare) series, but they are not isomorphic.

Comment: This example appears in exercise 4.1.16(b) from Bruns and Herzog.